# How would I go about reverse-engineering RF lights?

Tags: rf, wireless

I have some ceiling fans and lights throughout the house that we control with RF remotes. I'd like to be able to automate these lights with my raspberry pi, but in order to do that I'd need to figure out the frequency and how the remotes communicate. Advice?

Comment: Have you tried looking up their FCC IDs?

Answer (score 1):

start with a teardown, either do your own, or view one by an "expert" on you-tube.

you need to know three things,  what the RF frequency is, what the modulation scheme is and what the data protocol is

It may be that the makers have used a common RF chip like NRF2201 in which case you could start with a NRF2201 module and need less detailed knowledge of the RF protocol...

Answer (score 0):

Check the FCC Id for hints. Check the remote for crystal with a frequency stamp on them. Use a software defined radio module to scan radiowaves for hints.

Reverse engineering RF protocols involve alot of testing. If you don't know the frequency it works on then your job is much harder. Then you have to contend with encryption and  revolving codes depending on the protocol.

Comment: Software defined radio module... can you elaborate?

Comment: A SDR is a radio you control with software. It's a tool you can use to listen to an arbitrary frequency range. Google "sdr hacking" for a ton of info.

Comment: SDR is often a modifued (or unmodified) TV receiver USB stick used with hobbyist software

Answer (score 0):

You need to tear it down first to know what chipset they are using. From chipset, you will get to know the i) frequency it operates on and ii) possibly the physical layer protocol/modulation scheme it uses. A chipset can be capable of operating over multiple wireless protocols(e.g. AT86RF215 can use any of FSK, PSK, QAM etc). If this is the case then you will need to observe transmitted signal over spectrum analyzer or oscilloscope and identify the modulation protocol being used (This can be a really tough job). But if the chipset is like Si4421 which can use only one protocol then life becomes much simpler.

You will also need to know its higher layer data protocol (e.g. frame format indicating how the information is encapsulated in the physical layer frame, addressing scheme to different devices, any encryption it uses etc). Look if any documentation about this is available online.

All of the above (knowing modulation scheme and higher layer protocol) can become simple if its possible to acquire or reverse engineer the software stack on which the system is running.